# Apache POI, cant get Link Url

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I have excel file with Links, cells have next values:

`HYPERLINK("http://linkUrl.com","Link Label")`

I'm able to fetch link label by calling `cell..getStringCellValue()`, but I'm not able to fetch link URL, for some reasons `cell.getHyperlink()` returns `null`

Comment: The cell itself does not have a hyperlink. The cell contains a formula which causes a hyperlink while formula evaluating. So you needs getting the cell formula and get the link target from that formula.

Comment: @Axel Richter, I was trying to use FormulaEvaluator also but result is the same, I'm only able to get label

Comment: `FormulaEvaluator` from `apache poi` will not help here. It is `Excel` only what causes the link. Get the formula string from the cell using [Cell.getCellFormula](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getCellFormula-). Then you can get the link out of that formula string.

Comment: @AxelRichter, you telling that the only possible way to get this url it's parse String manually? It's strange that API don't provide any possibility to get args from Formula.

Comment: Oh, `apache poi` provides parsing formulas into formula tokens using [EvaluationWorkbook.getFormulaTokens](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/EvaluationWorkbook.html#getFormulaTokens-org.apache.poi.ss.formula.EvaluationCell-). But using this way is much over-complicated for the use case simply to get the string `http://linkUrl.com` from the string `HYPERLINK("http://linkUrl.com","Link Label")`.